# How to read .mdb file in zip folder without unzipping it in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query that would normally look out for and read .mdb files. However lately the .mdb are zipped due to large size. Seeing that adding the zip folder into the path doesn't work. I'm pretty lost.

I've tried adding VBA codes from online forums into the module, but have no idea how they work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

For reference I'm using MS access 2010.

EDIT: To clarify my question, I currently don't have VBA codes because I have no idea how the previous one works.

My question summed up is basically:

In SQL:
(BEFORE) `Select a,b,c From A,B,C IN "C:\test\test.mdb"`

(What I want) `Select a,b,c From A,B,C IN "C:\test\test.zip\test.mdb"`

How to read the test.mdb within test.zip without unzipping it?

Comment: Please elaborate on "look out for".

Comment: Er... Can Access open zipped databases at all? (As far as I know it cannot, but I could be wrong.) If it cannot, then VBA won't somehow make it available.

Comment: If you add the code you are trying to use to access the zipped files, and explain exactly why it isn't working, that would be a good start to making this an answerable question.